# I am trying to insert two variables for time and date but I am getting an error

Tags: python-3.x

In python, I have this portion of a script:

```
ip = ['10.25.128.225', '10.25.128.223', '10.25.128.224', '10.25.128.241']
time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

for address in ip:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((address, 9999))
    if result != 0:
        print('There is an issue with the {} address at {} on {} '.format(address, time, date))
```

Whenever I run the code, however, I get and error:

```
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I am thinking that I have to establish a data type, but I am still kind of new to python/programming. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Name you time variable differently - it shadows `time` module

Answer (score 1):

The `time` module is being overwritten by `time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`, which returns a string object. You may add a trailing underscore: `time_ = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` or change the name to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake: `time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

time is now a string, no more the `time` object that you used to produce the time string. You have to rename the left `time`